# Gemfile.old not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I made some changes in the Gemfile but I wanted to keep track of what was in the previous one. So I just changed the old one to Gemfile.old expectind it would be ignored. But after some changes and running bundle the rails server simply stopped running due to not finding this file.

here is the log.

```
/Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/definition.rb:22:in `build': /Users/viniciusbolzani/work/cart/Gemfile.old not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler.rb:155:in `definition'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `setup'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/work/cart/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/work/cart/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/viniciusbolzani/work/cart/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have a clue why Rails would be identifying that extension as a real file and requiring it?

Comment: btw. I just restored the Gemfile.old and run the bundle. Besides Gemfile.lock rails generated Gemfile.old.lock and now the rails server is running just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think there is something wrong with your configuration.

Inside the bin directory inside your application there are a few executable files that specify how the Gemfile filename should be handled. The default file name is Gemfile but it may have been changed somehow.

I would suggest you execute

```
grep -R -i -n 'Gemfile.old' *
```

on the root of your application and check if there are any references somewhere with this name. And if that's the case change it accordingly.

Comment: That worked. I found out that Gemfile.old was set as default reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to store the old version of Gemfile as rails considers all the gems mentioned in the file named as Gemfile , you can use versioning tools like github or bitbucket for this purpose .

Every time you add a new gem , the Gemfile.lock file adds the gem name and version to it just to make sure that it knows about the last change you made . In cases such as these , where you intend to keep multiple files of the same name , it might end up creating more confusion .Also the Gemfile.lock stores all the versions of the gem used so that you have an idea what all version numbers were used .

Comment: thanks for the comment. In fact that just created more confusion. I still don't know how to find out why rails is looking for that file though. I need to find out where it has been set as default reference for rails to keep looking for that when running the application.